# pipreqs does not show versions of the packages correctly in the conda virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I have Flask and matplotlib libraries installed in base and their versions are 1.0.2 and 3.1.1, respectively. On the other hand, on conda virtualenv has the following versions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu2Tz.png)
When I listed packages using pipreqs to create requirements.txt file while I am working in virtualenv, I see that the versions of libraries do not match with the ones in virtualenv.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqbEn.png)
Versions listed with pipreqs consistent with the those in base environment. Does anyone know why I am having this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.